# What does "To get on a high horse" mean?

Tags: idiom-meaning

Here is the phrase:

*I'm going to get on a high horse here and say that it worries me that developers think client-side rendering is faster.*

I think I can understand the meaning of the whole phrase, but I would like to know the specific meaning of this expression so as not to misuse it.

Comment: It's an idiom; you should Google for *"high-horse" idiom*. Here's [one definition](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/on+one's+high+horse) that search returns. Bear in mind that in general it's *not possible* to deduce the meaning of an idiom (a fixed phrase) from its component words. You must recognize you're dealing with an idiom and look up the phrase as a unit.

Comment: The idiom means that the speaker, at the risk of sounding arrogant, snooty, highfaluting, hoity toity, and so on, will venture to state his humble opinion anyway. Another way of saying the same thing is the idiom "In my humble opinion . . .." In other words, one's opinion may seem to others to be anything but humble. It may even give others the impression that you're getting on your high horse!

Comment: Somewhat related: ["Where do you get off...?" Origin](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/144146/where-do-you-get-off-origin/145387#145387)

Comment: As no-one else seems to have mentioned it, I feel I should point out that idiomatically it's almost always *get on **your** (**my, his**, etc.) high horse*. It's far from unknown, but the indefinite article *get on **a** high horse* sounds at least *slightly* odd to me (that's just a UK perspective - I don't know about AmE).

Comment: @FumbleFingers That was actually mentioned in Rusty Tuba’s answer. ;-)

Comment: @Janus: I was lazy. Given OP's context (and the fact that I personally didn't expect to learn anything by reading all the answers and comments), I simply searched the page for ***my high***. I think I also checked for ***your high***, but I never thought to look for ***one's high***.

Comment: Just be sure you don't confuse *get on a high horse* with *get high on a horse* or, worse yet, *get high on a high horse*. In the last case, both you and the horse are taking a chance (though perhaps having a good time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Dan Bron's comment points to, the basic definition of "getting on one's high horse" is:

> Behaving arrogantly and pompously

(from Dictionary.com)

However, sometimes understanding *meaning* does not necessarily translate into wise or effective usage, and the example deserves some explanation.

In fact, the instance quoted in the question (from http://openmymind.net/2012/5/30/Client-Side-vs-Server-Side-Rendering/) should not be taken as the most common application, for two reasons:

1) we most commonly see this expression phrased as **to get on one's high horse**, not "get on a high horse"

2) almost all of the instances of this idiom that you will find (in speech and writing) come in critical reference to the behavior, attitude, assertions, soap-boxisms, etc. of *another person*, as opposed to oneself

In the quotation in question, it is used (atypically) to preempt accusations of arrogance or pedantry.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your usage is from [here;](http://openmymind.net/2012/5/30/Client-Side-vs-Server-Side-Rendering/) I wanted to get a little more context. The author is recognizing that his comments may be perceived as conceited, since he is accusing web developers of not understanding a basic aspect of their work.

The basic high horse idiom has been linked in comments above, but I thought it would be beneficial to parse it as the author used it.

(This question might also benefit from moving to ELL.)

Comment: I understand why many perceive questions like this to be more suitable for ELL, but I think they provide fertile ground for an exploration not just of meaning (ascertainable to a certain extent through common dictionary sources), but of usage, currency, context, register, and syntax.

Comment: @Rusty: Those considerations are equally if not *more* relevant to ELL. The base assumption on ELU is usually that querants already *know* how English is actually used, so it's not necessarily worth bothering to point out that some usage is dated, formal, or whatever. But it's implicit in the site scope that learners on ELL *don't* know such things, even though they're obviously important.

Comment: I find it problematic to divide users into those who know how English is "actually used" and those who don't know. There are many active non-native English-speaking contributors who have much greater insight into the language (and provide better scholarship) than many native English-speaking contributors. The mere existence of this site demonstrates lack of consensus among those who apparently "know."